# Why is $auth->loggedIn never true in my use of CGI::Session::Auth::DBI?

Tags: perl, authentication, cgi

Using the examples from the [CGI::Session::Auth::DBI](http://search.cpan.org/%7Egeewiz/CGI-Session-Auth-1.06/Auth/DBI.pm) and [CGI::Session::Auth](http://search.cpan.org/%7Egeewiz/CGI-Session-Auth-1.06/Auth.pm) pages, I have attempted to implement the `_login` function with no success. I'm using Windows 7 and Apache 2.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;

use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser);

use CGI;
use CGI::Session;
use CGI::Session::Auth::DBI;

my $cgi = new CGI;

# using '.' directory for testing
my $session = new CGI::Session(undef, $cgi, {Directory=>'.'});
my $auth = new CGI::Session::Auth::DBI({
    CGI => $cgi,
    Session => $session,
    DSN => 'dbi:mysql:dbname=foobar:host=localhost',
    DBUser => 'foo',
    DBPasswd => 'bar',
    UserTable => 'cgi_auth_user' # auth_user already in use
});

print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";

if ($auth->_login("admin", "admin")) {
    print "<p>login ok</p>";
} else {
    print "<p>login fail</p>";
}

if ($auth->loggedIn) {
    print "<p>logged in; go to <a href='index.pl'>index</a></p>";
} else {
    print "<p>not logged in</p>";
}
```

The rendered output from this is:

```
login ok
not logged in
```

If I change the values passed to `_login` to "foo", "bar" (an invalid username/password), then I get this rendered result:

```
login fail
not logged in
```

I'm using '.' just for testing as I know it's a dir I can write to. Every time I run the code, a `cgisess_` file is created (e.g. `cgisess_9fb493cc9155ee9dd2b18fddc38139d8`), but this is created regardless of if I use a correct username or not. No errors are being returned, but `$auth->loggedIn` is always false.

The documentation says that `_login` is virtual, and it sounds like the DBI module overrides this, but I'm not sure.

What could I be doing wrong?

### Update 1:

I've also tried using `$auth->authenticate()` before the call to `$auth->loggedIn` but this has no effect. I've also tried using `$auth->authenticate()` and `$auth->loggedIn` on another after successful login, but I get the same result. No matter what I do, `$auth->loggedI` is always false.

### Update 2:

I've also tried chaning the directory to "/" and all it does is create the `cgisess` files in `/` rather than current dir.

### Update 3:

I figured it may be an issue with the database records; I'm using the default example ones from the example page, but with a modified admin password. Here's a phpMyAdmin export:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `cgi_auth_user` (
  `userid` char(32) collate utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(30) collate utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `passwd` varchar(30) collate utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL default '',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`userid`),
  UNIQUE KEY `username` (`username`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

INSERT INTO `cgi_auth_user` (`userid`, `username`, `passwd`) VALUES
('325684ec1b028eaf562dd484c5607a65', 'admin', 'admin'),
('ef19a80d627b5c48728d388c11900f3f', 'guest', 'guest');
```

Then again, if `_login` is returning `true` with a valid username and password, then I would assume that the userid is valid... No?

### Update 4:

I've also tested this on our Linux production server, and I get the exact same issue.

Comment: Avoid using indirect object notation (i.e. `new CGI`). Use method invocation syntax (i.e. `CGI->new`). See http://perldoc.perl.org/perlobj.html#Indirect-Object-Syntax and http://perlbuzz.com/mechanix/2008/02/the-perils-of-perl-5s-indirect.html

Comment: I just looked a the code, and the ::DBI module *does* override _login. As for why your code's not working: is the database set up? Have you looked in the error log? Can you turn on debugging?

Comment: Yeah the DB is set up and working; to prove this I changed to a false DB username and got a DB error. Should I turn on debug info using a `perl` switch? I looked at `--help` but I don't understand about the debug part; maybe this should be a new question?

Comment: $auth->Log=1
(from perusing the source)

Comment: You could try running it with the Perl debugger - I personally find it a little bit confusing. I guess if you can run the CGI script from the command line this is a viable option. The Auth modules do have inbuilt debug statements though - look in the source. As ergosys points out, there's a Log flag (to <code>new</code>). I think you may also need to provide an initialised Log4Perl object... Sorry not an expert on these modules (never used them) just trying to help ;-)

Comment: @FalseVinylShrub I tried Log::Log4perl but I'm not sure how to see the output.

Comment: @ergosys Error message is: Can't locate object method "Log" via package "CGI::Session::Auth::DBI"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try outputting the results of `$session->header()` as the first thing you output. This should set your cookie and load the existing session instead of creating a new one each time.

Also, `_login()` only performs the authentication with the database, but does not modify the `$auth` object. Using `authenticate()`, you need to define the username and password using the `param()` function of your `$cgi` object. You need to set the fields `log_username` and `log_password` for the `authenticate()` function to work.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;

use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser);

use CGI;
use CGI::Session;
use CGI::Session::Auth::DBI;

my $cgi = CGI->new;
my $session = new CGI::Session(undef, $cgi, {Directory=>'/tmp'});

my $auth = new CGI::Session::Auth::DBI({
    CGI => $cgi,
    Session => $session,
    DSN => 'dbi:mysql:dbname=foobar:host=localhost',
    DBUser => 'foo',
    DBPasswd => 'bar',
    UserTable => 'cgi_auth_user'
});

print $session->header();

$cgi->param('log_username', 'admin');
$cgi->param('log_password', 'admin');

$auth->authenticate();

if ($auth->loggedIn) {
    print "<p>logged in; go to <a href='index.pl'>index</a></p>";
} else {
    print "<p>not logged in</p>";
}
```

I haven't tested it, but this should be working.

Comment: Perfect; I wonder if this is a hack way of doing it? The example code doesn't mention that we need to set `$cgi->param` -- I would assume it would use POST values, but I tried this and no luck. Anyway, your answer works, so thanks!

Comment: Ah! Actually I just re-tried with POST and it turns out you need to use log_ before the field names: `print '<form method="post"><input type="text" name="log_username" /><input type="password" name="log_password" /><input type="submit" /></form>';`

Comment: I believe you could also use GET, but that would not be too secure. ;)

Answer (score 1):

The doc is pretty clear that you have to override the _login() method, unless guest/guest works for you.  Plus you aren't calling authenticate(), which actually invokes _login(), you shouldn't be doing it.

> _login()
>
> This virtual method performs the
>   actual login attempt by comparing the
>   login form data the visitor sent with
>   some local user database. The _login
>   method of the base class
>   CGI::Session::Auth only knows the user
>   'guest' with password 'guest'.
>
> To access a real user database, you
>   have to use a subclass that modifies
>   the _login method appropriately. See
>   the modules in the Auth/ subdirectory.

Comment: The "See the modules in the Auth/ subdirectory." part is a little misleading I think; since `CGI::Session::Auth::DBI` is in the Auth/ subdirectory (isn't it?) so it lead me to assume that this module overrides `_login`...

Comment: By the way, `_login` returns true when I use a valid username and password, and false when I use false credentials. So I believe that I'm using it correctly. I will update my answer.

Comment: Yeah after looking at it a bit I see _login() is overridden by DBI. authenticate() seems to use "log_password", "log_username" by default though.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the source code and documentation, `_login()` never actually sets the internal `loggedin` flag.  That is only performed in the authenticate module.  You should also remember that it is generally accepted perl practice that methods starting with '_' should be treated essentially as private methods, (or in Java terminology perhaps protected) only to be used by subclasses.  So you shouldn't be using _login directly.

> LoginVarPrefix: By default, CGI::Session::Auth expects the username and password of the visitor to be passed in the form variables 'log_username' and 'log_password'. To avoid conflicts, the prefix 'log_' can be altered by this parameter.

I believe this will work

```
$session->param('log_username', 'admin');
$session->param('log_password', 'admin');

$auth->authenticate(); # no return value to check

print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";

if ($auth->loggedIn) {
    print "<p>logged in; go to <a href='index.pl'>index</a></p>";
} else {
    print "<p>not logged in</p>";
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this a shot tomorrow.

Comment: Hmm still returning "not logged in" -- I copied and pasted your code.

Comment: Aha! Almost, take a look at Wolf's answer. The code looks at $cgi params and not $session params.

Answer (score 0):

You can turn on logging by putting this above the my $cgi = new CGI; line

```
use Log::Log4perl qw(:easy);
# Set priority of root logger to DEBUG
Log::Log4perl->easy_init($DEBUG);
```

This will turn on debugging and allow you to see more of what is going on.

Comment: Thanks, this will be helpful I think.

Comment: I had to install Log::Log4perl -- the page loads ok, but how can I see the debug output?